# Can not remove decimal from number input field. Is it a bug?

Tags: html, validation, input

There is an input field with the `type="number"` loaded with default decimal value. When I want to remove the decimal and submit the form, It gives me validation error (on Chrome) and forces to use decimal. Should I use any special attribute or this is a bug? Besides I don't want to use `step="1"` because sometimes I may need decimals.

```html
<form action="?">
<input type="number" value="123.2423">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN web docs -](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#allowing_decimal_values)

> The default stepping value for `number` inputs is 1, allowing only
> integers to be entered—*unless* the stepping base is not an integer.

The number inputs has `step` size **1** by default. If you want to allow to have a value that requires decimals, you'll need to reflect this in the `step` value (e.g. step="0.0001" to allow decimals to four decimal places).

```html
<form action="?">
<input type="number" value="123.2423" step="0.0001">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Still can not update a field which loaded with decimal data.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Its working for me, i added working snippet in the answer, please check.

Comment: It is partially working. If the number of decimals is not equal to the step, will not work

Comment: @AliSheikhpour, as you can see in the docs number expects only integer value but if you want to allow decimal value, you have to use `step` attribute so probably you need to set the `step` value dynamically based on the input decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug because whenever you use type="number" browser usually expect number input it can be decimal value.
Here how it is to be done

Enter a number:
  
  Submit

Comment: If the filed is loaded with decimal values, can not update to integer and update.